# Show flyouts from hamburger button

Tags: windows, uwp-xaml, hamburger-menu, flyout

I would like to show a flyout from an hamburger button... like it happens into Windows 10 logout (see the picture).

It's possibile?!?

[image]

---

Jessica thanks for your reply but in my code where I can put yours!?!

```
<Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo x:Name="LogoutButton" PageParameter="0" ButtonType="Command" Tapped="LogoutButton_Tapped">  
    <Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo.NavigationTransitionInfo>  
        <SuppressNavigationTransitionInfo />  
    </Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo.NavigationTransitionInfo>  
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">  
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>  
            <TextBlock Text="Logout" x:Uid="logout_ToolTipService" TextWrapping="Wrap" />  
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>  
        <SymbolIcon Width="48" Height="48" Symbol="Contact" />  
        <TextBlock Margin="12,0,0,0" Name="textBlock_LogoutButton"  x:Uid="textBlock_LogoutButton" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Logout" />  
    </StackPanel>  
</Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo>
```

Comment: You can put `MenuFlyout` on any button let alone Hamburger button.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what are you meaning!!!

Comment: ...and why downvote?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button>  
    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE700;" />  
    <Button.Flyout>  
        <MenuFlyout>  
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Some text"/>  
            <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Some text 2"/>  
            <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Some text 3"/>  
        </MenuFlyout>  
    </Button.Flyout>  
</Button>
```